# Copying recipes and data bags to another instance

Tags: chef-infra

I need to copy recipes and databags from one instance of Chef 11.x to another, which is a fresh install.  Environments, nodes, clients etc.. will be different. I am seeking a method to do this. Does any one have any experience of doing this, and if so what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [knife download](https://docs.chef.io/knife_download.html) command to grab your data bag `knife download data_bags`

You can then upload them to the new server using `knife data bag from file` https://docs.chef.io/knife_data_bag.html#from-file. Additionally, the [knife backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup) plugin might be a good option for you. With that, you can do `knife backup export data_bags`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [method](https://getchef.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000598806-Migrate-Chef-Server-Data) if you plan to do it manually from your local machine since this is based on knife work station. To do in a better way, you could try to setup a jenkins instance to do this for you. You need to have a service account which has access to chef so that jenkins can upload these with that account. But this will be useful in long run when you need to upload any cookbook or databag or any chef artifact which is source controlled in github, bitbucket etc.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After posting the question, I happened to stumble across the resource shown in the link. It could prove to be of some help and I'll be working through it today.  Re: the Jenkins suggestion, maybe overkill for the current one off quick and dirty exercise, but the approach worth bearing in mind for future use